# How to convert XLSX file to CSV with font formats in java

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to convert my xls file to csv file. my java code convert text properly. but i'm not getting any font formatting and other formatting.
so how can i get my font formatting in my CSV(open in excel) file.

```
public class XlsxtoCSV {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
             FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/blackpearl/Downloads/file.xlsx"));
             HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
             HSSFSheet  my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 

             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
             FileWriter my_csv=new FileWriter("/home/blackpearl/Downloads/Newfile.csv");
             CSVWriter my_csv_output=new CSVWriter(my_csv); 
             while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                     Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                     int i=0;//String array
                     String[] csvdata = new String[20];
                     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                             while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                                     switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                             csvdata[i]= cell.getStringCellValue();                                              
                                             break;
                                     }
                                     i=i+1;
                             }
             my_csv_output.writeNext(csvdata);
             }
             System.out.println("file imported");
             my_csv_output.close(); //close the CSV file
             input_document.close(); //close xlsx file
     }
}
```

Comment: [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a plain text format. It is not able storing any formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV stands for comma-separated values. And it really is simply that. It’s text, with values separated by commas (or, in some versions, semi-colons or other delimiters). It’s basically a plain text file, and can be opened and edited with a text editor. It is not possible to include formatting information in that file format.